# Applets permissions when called from JS

Tags: java, security, applet

We need to get list of client local printers in JavaScript code. We know that JS can't access local resources. So we decided to use Java applet. We make applet and sign it, but when applet accessed from JavaScript code (untrusted code), it implies that the *signed applet* essentially behaves likes an *unsigned applet*. And unsigned applet can't access to local printer list.

What can I do to solve this problem (without using *java.policy* file, because we can't install this file to each client)?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for *"..without using java.policy file, because.."*  which supports that you have done some research.  (I won't post an answer, since Pablo seems to have nailed it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the problematic code (the code that throws the exception because of lack of permissions) in a [PrivilegedAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html) or a [PrivilegedExceptionAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction.html), and then call it using the *doPrivileged* methods of [AccessController](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html).